# How to avoid compression options pop up box in avisaveoptions

Tags: c#, screen-capture, avi, avvideocomposition

I am using AviFile api to make a screen capture video. I want to capture it as small videos of 2 minutes length instead of creating one single video at a stretch. When the video starts getting recorded, a pop-up box to chose the compression option is displayed by default when the avisaveoptions function is called. This creates a problem since I have to choose the option every 2 mins. I would like to avoid this by setting the default value to 'Microsoft Video 1'. How can I do this?